# What adhesive can I use for a teapot?

Tags: adhesive

Is there an adhesive that works well with ceramic and is heat-resistant? The application is a teapot that should sustain temperatures up to 100C-105C.

The [Devcon 5-minute epoxy](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000O60ZKK) worked, but easily detached when 100C water was poured in. This is getting hard to find for non-industrial uses.

Comment: There are adhesives that work fine on ceramics up to 1000C, not just 100C. But whether they are food-safe, and available in small quantities, is another question. FDA-approved "food safe" adhesives in the USA are low temperature epoxy based products that are useless at 100C.

Comment: Cotronics sells adhesives in small quantities that can withstand those temperatures, not sure about "food safe" though. Call or email them.